# The execution of a line command in C++ run without returning the expected result

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I'm using c++ within Qt creator to execute a command line:

```
cd c:\
mkdir sadok
```

That's why, I used these instrcutions:

```
   int i, j;
   i=system ("cd c:\\");
   cout<<"i: "<<i<<endl;
   j=system("mkdir sadok ");
```

But I had 2 problems:

1- The creation of new folder is always under default path and not under c:\

2- cmd appears and desappear very fast and without displaying anything.

Any help please.

Comment: This question is not related to Qt, Qt Creator or QProcess (from tags you defined).

Comment: By calling `system` you are starting a shell (cmd) and telling it to `cd c:\\ `. It is happy to oblige but this has no effect on your program. You cannot change current directory by calling `system`. Each OS has its own function to do so. You can try `chdir` but I have no idea if it is supported under Windows.

Comment: You are not actually using Qt, just QtCreator, so removing the qt tag.

Comment: Note, the accepted answer to the duplicate question does not actually answer this question. The next one down does. Also, you don't have to change directories to make a new directory anywhere. `mkdir ("c:\\sadok")` is just as good.

Comment: lpapp, Antwane I'm using qt but you can't see that because I published two instuctions and not all the project !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system ("cd c:\\");` just changes the working directory in the shell opened by `system()`, that doesn't change the current working directory of your program.

You may try to do

```
i=system ("cd c:\\; mkdir sadok");
```

or

```
i=system ("mkdir c:\\sadok");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with the following (much easier) code:

```
QDir dir;
dir.mkpath("C:\\sadok");
```